# Get admin id to visible comments for administrator also wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I am successfully able to restrict users to show comments only to them but the get_current_user_id() is only displaying user comments to only them but i want administrator to view their comments and reply to them on front. how to get adminid to use and apply on this condition

```html
<?php

/**
 * Used as a callback by wp_list_comments() for displaying the comments.
 */
function _s_comment( $comment, $args, $depth ) {
    $GLOBALS['comment'] = $comment;

    $current_user_id = get_current_user_id();

    if ( 'pingback' == $comment->comment_type || 'trackback' == $comment->comment_type ) : ?>

    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>" <?php comment_class(); ?>>
            <div class="comment-body">
            </div>

    <?php elseif ( $current_user_id == $comment->user_id ) : ?>

    <li id="comment-<?php comment_ID(); ?>"
```

I have modified my code. now users are able to see their comments and administrator is able to see all users comments. but still users are not able to see the comments of admin . they only see their's..how can achieve this.. I am beginner but still working hard to get solve on my own still people degrading by down voting my post.

```html
$current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

<?php elseif ( $current_user_id == $comment->user_id || ($current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator' ) : ?>
```

Comment: $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
<?php elseif ( $current_user_id == $comment->user_id || ($current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator' )  : ?>

I have modified my code. now users are able to see their comments and administrator is able to see all users comments. but still users are not able to see the comments of admin . they only see their's..how can achieve this..

I am beginner but still working hard to get solve on my own still people degrading by down voting my post.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if I user is admin, editor or author by the follow:

```
$user = wp_get_current_user();
$allowed_roles = array('editor', 'administrator', 'author');
<?php if( array_intersect($allowed_roles, $user->roles ) ) {  ?> 
       // admins or editors can do something
<?php } ?>
```

other option

```
<?php if( current_user_can('editor') || current_user_can('administrator') ) {  ?> 
    // admins or editors can do something
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: $current_user = wp_get_current_user(); 

<?php elseif ( $current_user_id == $comment->user_id || ($current_user->roles[0] == 'administrator' ) : ?>

Comment: I have modified my code now users are able to see their comment only and admin is able to see comment of him and all users but i want users to see admin comments also